# Distribution which is not in $H^{-1}(\mathbb{\Omega})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ denote the dual of $H^1_0(\Omega),$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ So clearly the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega):=(C_c^{\infty}(\Omega))'$ is a superset of $H^{-1}(\Omega).$ What are the examples of distribution which is not in $H^{-1}(\Omega)?$

Comment: Every linear functional defined on smooth functions that is not defined for $H^1$-functions will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that..Could you please mention one  explicit example

Comment: I also understand that that $H^-1$ is a combination of distributions of function type and derivative of distribution which is of function type

Comment: The Dirac delta at a point in $\Omega$ will be such an example when $n\geq 2$

Comment: @Jose27 I understand that Dirac delta is a distribution. How to prove that it does not belong to H^-1 for n geq 2?

Comment: Pick your favorite $u\in H^1_0$, with $u$ unbounded (this is where $n\geq 2$ comes in). Let $u_k := \min( k,\max(-k,u))$ (truncate $u$ at $\pm k$ so that $u_k$ is bounded). Then if $\delta$ was in $H^{-1}$ then we'd have $|\delta(u_k)|\lesssim \| u_k\|_{H^1}\leq \| u\|_{H^1}$, but this can't be if $\delta$ is centered at a point where $u$ becomes unbounded.

Comment: The above is not completely rigorous (you want to test $\delta$ with $u_k\in C_0^\infty$. But hopefully it gives the right idea.